# If $G$ is a group, $a,b,c,d\in G$ such that $cab=d$ and $dba=c,$ prove $a^4=e=b^4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to do the following exercise:

Hypotheses: $G$ is a group, $a,b,c,d$ are elements in $G$ such that $cab=d$ and $dba=c.$

Conclusion: prove that $a^4=e=b^4$.

There's a hint: first compute $aba$ and $bab.$

At this moment the only relations I obtained are $ab^2a=e, ab^2=b^2a, ab=(ba)^{-1}$ and the relations obtained from these ones by switching $a$ and $b.$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know about presentations, this is like studying $$P\cong \langle a,b,c,d\mid cab=d, dba=c\rangle.$$

Comment: If $a = b^{-1}$ and $c=d$, then those conditions are satisfied, and we cannot derive anything about the orders of elements.  Did you make a typo anywhere or leave off any information?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I suspect there is an implicit hypothesis that $a,b,c,d$ are all distinct elements of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get further because in $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ you can take $a=2$, $b=4$, $c=d=0$. You will have $c+a+b=d, d+b+a=c$ but $4a=8\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

As written the conclusion you are trying to draw is incorrect. Let $G$ be any group, $c=d$, and $a$ any element with $a^{-1}=b$.

Even if there is the additional requirement that $c$ and $d$ are distinct, and equivalently, $ab \not = e$: Let $G$ be any finite group that has an element $x$ of order $6$, and such that $|G| >6$. Then what if $a=x^2$ and $b=x$, and $d$ is any element in $G$ that is not in $\langle x \rangle$, and $c=dx^3$ [and so $cx^3 = dx^6=de=d$].

ETA: An example would be $G=(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z},+)$, where $d=9$, $c=3$, and $a=4$ and $b=2$. Note that all $4$ elements $a,b,c,d$ are distinct.